# How to use the planning scene monitor in C++

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the correct way to create a MoveIt `PlanningSceneMonitor` in C++ for the default planning scene managed by the move group node? (With the default move group node, I mean the one launched by the `demo.launch` file of a MoveIt configuration package for a robot.)

In the [planning_scene](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/planning_scene/planning_scene_tutorial.html) tutorial is written:

> This is, however, not the recommended way to instantiate a PlanningScene. The [PlanningSceneMonitor](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_ros_planning/html/classplanning__scene__monitor_1_1PlanningSceneMonitor.html) is the recommended method to create and maintain the current planning scene

However, the [planning_scene_monitor](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/planning_scene_monitor/planning_scene_monitor_tutorial.html) tutorial does not contain a concrete example of how to use the `PlanningSceneMonitor` class. (This is in the latest branch of the tutorials, the tutorial does not exist yet in melodic.)

I found an example in [moveit_visual_tools](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_visual_tools/blob/a4f91ce1c71f866d804bba445a353f6ba9be3c4f/src/moveit_visual_tools.cpp#L85), but there is a lot going on there that I don't understand. As far as I understand, it creates a separate one, not connected to the move group node.

- What monitors should I start to enable collision checking between the robot and the scene?
- When should I call the update method?

As done in [these lines](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_visual_tools/blob/a4f91ce1c71f866d804bba445a353f6ba9be3c4f/src/moveit_visual_tools.cpp#L136) of code:

```
planning_scene_monitor::LockedPlanningSceneRW scene(getPlanningSceneMonitor());
scene->getCurrentStateNonConst().update();  // TODO: remove hack to prevent bad transforms
```

**More context for the questions**

For the development of a new planner, I'm using the planner through the plugin interface. I have an instance of `planning_interface::PlannerManager`, called `planner_instance` which can then be used for motion planning in the following way:

```
planning_interface::MotionPlanRequest req; // fill in this request ...
planning_interface::MotionPlanResponse res;

// somehow get access to the planning scene
planning_scene = ...

auto context = planner_instance->getPlanningContext(planning_scene, req, res.error_code_);
bool success = context->solve(res);
```

I have difficulty understanding how to use the planning scene from the move_group node, or creating one myself. Currently, I can add collision objects using moveit_visual_tools.

```
moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualTools mvt("/base_link", "/visualization_marker_array");
mvt.publishCollisionCuboid(box_pose, 0.3, 0.1, 1.0, "box_1");
mvt.trigger();

auto planning_scene_monitor = mvt.getPlanningSceneMonitor();
planning_scene_monitor::LockedPlanningSceneRW planning_scene(planning_scene_monitor);
// (clean alternative for planning_scene_monitor.getPlanningScene())
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356183/how-to-use-the-planning-scene-monitor-in-c++/) by [jeroendm](https://answers.ros.org/users/36697/jeroendm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2020-07-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

visual tools is only for visualization purpose I believe. To add or remove collision objects you need to use `PlanningSceneInterface`, methods like `addCollisionObjects` and `removeCollisionObjects`

For collision checking you can use:

> ```
> planning_scene_monitor::LockedPlanningSceneRO(planning_scene_monitor)->checkCollision(collision_request, collsion_result)
> ```

In general, I would say:

- Use `PlanningSceneInterface` to add/remove objects to the scene.
- Use `PlanningSceneMonitor` to keep track of the updated planning scene. `LockedPlanningSceneRO` gives access to the up-to-date planning scene instance. From there you can do things like collision checking or other methods from planning scene.
- Use `MoveGroupInterface` to set targets, planners and do the actual motion planning

About the `PlanningSceneMonitor` tutorial, I agree it needs a comprehensive example so referring from `PlanningScene` tutorial makes sense.

---

Originally posted by [Omid](https://answers.ros.org/users/48983/omid/) with karma: 21 on 2020-07-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand the recommendations in Omid's answer, but it does not contain instructions to create the `PlanningSceneMonitor` yet, so that's why added this answer.

To create a planning scene monitor that is up to date with the planning scene maintained by the move_group node, you can do the following:

```
auto psm = std::make_shared<planning_scene_monitor::PlanningSceneMonitor>("robot_description");
psm->startSceneMonitor("/move_group/monitored_planning_scene");
```

The planning scene monitor will subscribe to the ROS topic `/move_group/monitored_planning_scene` published by the move_group node.

However, this does not take into account collision objects that were published before the node was launched. Getting the planning scene monitor `psm` up to date with the existing scene is achieved through a ROS service request to a service `/get_planning_scene` published by the move_group node.

```
bool success = psm->requestPlanningSceneState("/get_planning_scene");
```

This leaves us with a planning scene monitor that allows us access to an up to date `PlanningScenePtr`. I understand that this pointer should not be used in "normal" MoveIt use.

(There are many more ways to interact with the planning scene monitor, but this is the one I wanted to understand.)

**Edit**: I created a minimal working example [here](https://github.com/JeroenDM/moveit_planning_scene_example).

---

Originally posted by [jeroendm](https://answers.ros.org/users/36697/jeroendm/) with karma: 168 on 2020-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8